In the following code, when i rent a car, after i enter the end date for the rental, it just stops working
This is my code, after i enter the end date for the rental, it just freezes for a few seconds waiting for input, then it just throws out an error: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005), which i think is related to memory access violation.
It's a 3 part code program where there is Administration, Authentication, and Client, and after  debugging, I'm certain that the error is in the rentCar and writeCar part of the code.
#include "Client.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

Car* readCarsFromCSV(const string& filename, int& numCars) {
    ifstream file(filename);
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cout << "Error: Unable to open " << filename << " for reading." << endl;
        numCars = 0;
        return nullptr;
    }

    Car* cars = nullptr;
    string line;
    int index = 0;
    while (getline(file, line)) {
        if (line.empty()) continue;

        stringstream ss(line);
        if (index == 0) {
            cars = new Car[1];
        }
        else {
            Car* temp = new Car[index + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < index; ++i) {
                temp[i] = cars[i];
            }
            delete[] cars;
            cars = temp;
        }

        getline(ss, cars[index].plateNumber, ',');
        getline(ss, cars[index].brand, ',');
        string yearStr;
        getline(ss, yearStr, ',');
        bool validYear = true;
        for (char c : yearStr) {
            if (!isdigit(c)) {
                validYear = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (validYear && !yearStr.empty()) {
            cars[index].year = stoi(yearStr);
        }
        else {
            cerr << "Invalid year: '" << yearStr << "' in line: " << line << endl;
            cars[index].year = 0;
        }

        getline(ss, cars[index].model, ',');
        string priceStr;
        getline(ss, priceStr, ',');
        try {
            cars[index].pricePerDay = stod(priceStr);
        }
        catch (const invalid_argument& e) {
            if (!priceStr.empty()) {
                cerr << "Invalid price: " << priceStr << " in line: " << line << endl;
            }
            cars[index].pricePerDay = 0.0;
        }
        getline(ss, cars[index].color);
        index++;
    }
    file.close();
    numCars = index;
    return cars;

}



void writeRentalCarsToCSV(const Rental* rentals, int numRentals) {
    ofstream file("C:\\Games\\Car Rental Program\\rentalcars.csv");
    if (!file.is_open()) {
        cout << "Error: Unable to open rentalcars.csv for writing." << endl;
        return;
    }

    file << "User ID,Plate Number,Start Date,End Date" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < numRentals; ++i) {

        if (i < numRentals && rentals[i].idNumber != "" && rentals[i].plateNumber != "" && rentals[i].d.startDate != "" && rentals[i].d.endDate != "") {
            file << rentals[i].idNumber << "," << rentals[i].plateNumber << "," << rentals[i].d.startDate << "," << rentals[i].d.endDate << endl;
        }
    }

    file.close();
    cout << "Rented cars data written to rentalcars.csv successfully." << endl;

}


bool checkAvailability(const Rental* rentals, int numRentals, const string& plateNumber, const string& rentedDate) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numRentals; ++i) {
        if (rentals[i].plateNumber == plateNumber && rentals[i].d.startDate <= rentedDate && rentals[i].d.endDate >= rentedDate) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}
void rentCar(Rental*& rentals, int& numRentals, const string& plateNumber, const string& startDate, const string& endDate) { //this is where i believe the error is

    if (numRentals < 0) {
        cout << "Error: numRentals is not initialized properly." << endl;
        return;
    }

    if (numRentals % 10 == 0) {
        Rental* temp = new Rental[numRentals + 10];
        if (!temp) {
            cout << "Error: Memory allocation failed." << endl;
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numRentals; ++i) {
            temp[i] = rentals[i];
        }
        delete[] rentals;
        rentals = temp;
    }

    rentals[numRentals] = { to_string(numRentals + 1), plateNumber, {startDate, endDate} };
    ++numRentals;

    writeRentalCarsToCSV(rentals, numRentals);
    cout << "Car rented successfully!" << endl;

}


This is quite a lot of code. Reducing it to a [mre] will help us help you.

Ok will do, ill edit it

I am much less certain than you are about the location of the cause of the problem.

Notes : This is C++ so no do not return a raw pointer if you want to return a collection (array) of cars. Car* readCarsFromCSV should be std::vector<Car> readCarsFromCSV this has the added benefit that you now know how many cars you will have loaded from file. Just remember raw new/delete and owning raw pointers should be avoided! (Even if most C++ teachers still teach new/delete from day 1). Returning nullptr is just asking for trouble

Who or what is teaching you C++, since it looks like they're not doing a great job of it

@PepijnKramer The thing is i was previously using vector but the dr at our uni told us not to use these types of libraries as they're considered cheating, so i've been trying to find a workaround to fix it but i simply just cant

Then I would really really want a talk with your teacher, because it is NOT cheating.  This is how C++ should be used and he should read this C++ core guidelines. In the case that this is a datastructures class the fact that you wanted to use std::vector should be a sign. You are missing something that does what std::vector is doing.. so go ahead and make a class that mimmicks a vector (doesn't have to be templated, just a CarsCollection class will do)

Show your teacher this Stop teaching "C". And if std::vector is cheating so is using std::ifstring, std::string etc.. so your professor is inconsistent too ;)

@PepijnKramer I've got it! It was just getting stuck for some reason on trying to convert this date that im entering into a bool for some reason even though it literally doesnt exist in the code. Thanks alot for the help.

Here is a quick demo : https://onlinegdb.com/AVAMY9KYi

The thing is i was previously using vector but the dr at our uni told us not to use these types of libraries as they're considered cheating, -- And it is teaching this type of foolishness makes students drop C++ and go to python or some other language.  The vector class has been officially part of C++ for 26 years now.  That is probably older than most people in your class.

Second, if this is a data structures class, it is highly unfair to wrap a "car rental" question as a "data structures" question, where you have to implement every single data structure being used "by hand".  In the real world, C++ programmers would have focused on the car rental details and implementing them using ready-made tools, something every other major high-level language would have done.  If the course you are taken were honest, they would have assigned you to create your own vector class instead of some high-level "implement a car rental app" assignment.
